# Pandas count average number of unique numbers across groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that contain columns household_key, age_group, income_group and day. For each household, there is a row for each day that household went shopping. I want to find on average how many distinct days each age group went shopping in the study period. I tried grouping by age group and counting the number of unique dates, but I want to get the unique dates per household in each group, not just the unique dates in each group, then I want things like mean and standard deviation. I have tried:

```
df.groupby('age_group', as_index=False).agg({'DAY': 'nunique'})
```

But this ignores the households, I also tried:

```
df.groupby(['age_group', 'household_key'], as_index=False).agg({'DAY': 'nunique'})
```

but this gets me one group per household (each household is in one age group). Then I don't know how to get the information by age group. I want to do some sort of multilevel group but I don't know how. I'm using Pandas in Python 3.

Comment: Could you include a sample of your data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, first you want to aggregate over each `age` and `household`:

```
agg = (df.groupby(['age_group', 'household_key'])
         .agg({'DAY': 'nunique'})
      )
```

and then groupby again for the mean, e.g.,

```
agg.groupby('age_group').mean()
```

will give you the mean for each `age_group` across the `household_key`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'household_key':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
        'age_group':[25,25,25,25,30,30,30,25,25,25],
        'income_group':[40,40,40,40,40,40,40,30,30,30],
        'day':['2019-01-01','2019-01-05','2019-01-08','2019-01-15','2019-01-01','2019-01-08','2019-01-10','2019-01-01','2019-01-05','2019-01-10']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# get group by household
group1 = df.groupby(['household_key', 'age_group']).agg({'day': 'nunique'})
# get group by age_group
group2 = df.groupby(['age_group']).agg({'day': 'nunique'})
# join the results
group = group2.merge(group1, how='right', left_index=True, right_index=True)
group.columns = ['unique_days_in_group', 'unique_days_in_household']
print(group)
```

the result will be like this:

```
                         unique_days_in_group  unique_days_in_household
household_key age_group                                                
1             25                            5                         4
2             30                            3                         3
3             25                            5                         3
```